# Bash: Combining outputs of multiple commands

Tags: linux, bash, macos, grep, comm

I am trying to do the following
1. Find all files that contain the word gold
2. Find all files that contain the word sheep
3. Find the intersection of 1 and 2 above (those files that contain the word gold and sheep)

Here is how I am trying to do this in bash

```
comm -12i < (grep -l gold * | sort) < (grep -l sheep * | sort)
```

but I get the following error

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

A space after '(' doesn't help, and neither does taking it off. Why is this a problem and how do I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close:

> A space after '(' doesn't help, and neither does taking it off. Why is this a problem and how do I solve it?

The space *in front of* the `(` has to be deleted.

```
comm -12 <(grep -l gold * | sort) <(grep -l sheep * | sort)
```

On my system `comm` has no `-i` option, so I erased the `i` too.